# Jquery mobile back return to sane scroll

Tags: jquery-mobile

How I change the back browser action to return for same scroll?
I have two pages in my html screen.

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
   <a href="#page2">page2</a>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="page2">
  here is page 2
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

`Back` button is works by location `URL`. So make sure you create `URL` that suit your needs. I think `ionic-framework` that use `Angular` and `Angular-UI Router` is more suitable and convenient with your business needs. Also Ionic has built in `back` service that `records` our previous `state`.